# Excel 2016: Use a control form to cover up the Excel ribbon while a macro is running

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which does manipulations on the ribbon. Because it looks awkward for the user to see rapid automated actions on the ribbon, I would like to cover up the ribbon while the macro is running with a control form or some sort of a filled rectangle. Can you please suggest a solution for that?

EDIT: I tried creating a modeless form and positioned it over the ribbon. Unfortunately, as the macro runs, the actions still flicker through and their z-order seems to overpower that of the user form. I think I've exhausted everything considering this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698366/vba-application-screenupdating-equivalent-for-actions-on-the-excel-ribbon/57709113?noredirect=1#comment101902928_57709113) of mine, but who knows maybe there's something out there that will do the trick.

[image]

EDIT 2: As you can see in the GIF above, the macro actions still flicker through over the modeless user form even after setting the window position as top most, as suggested. I also tried showing and re-positioning the form after expanding the ribbon, but that causes a run-time error as the UI automation framework is not able to track-down the UI elements it needs to operate on next.

Comment: Did you try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work for actions done on the ribbon. I'm not really sure why you downvoted the post but ok.

Comment: `.. I'm not really sure why you downvoted the post but ok. –...` I did not downvote your post.

Comment: You could hide the application and then make it visible after the changes are done?

Comment: 1.`Application ScreenUpdating = False` doesn't work on the ribbon and the macro itself does actions that navigate through the ribbon a click a button                                 2.`Application.Visible = False` doesn't work either since it hides the UI tree and the macro cannot execute the actions.

Comment: Now I am curious as to what exactly are you doing with the ribbon... Possible to see the code?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, it's a macro that expands a ribbon tab and then click one of the buttons available. It uses the `UIAutomationClient` library natively available for reference in order to automate this action. You can see the code here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643879/excel-2016-clicking-simulating-a-click-using-a-vba-macro/57721667#57721667

Comment: You can also see the edit.

Comment: posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

To display a userform over a certain portion of the screen to cover something while code will do something to the ribbon behind it, we'll need a **modeless userform**.

As opposed to a modal userform, the modeless userform has the following advantage since it is a seperate window: **It can be displayed on top of the Excel window while the Excel Window keeps the focus.**

Let's say the name of the userform is `frmCoverScreen`. To invoke it as a modeless userform, we'd do:

```
frmCoverScreen.Show vbModeless
```

Now, we need to use the `SetWindowPos` function from the Windows API in order to make the form appear on top of the Excel Window at all times. We're also going to need the `FindWindow` function to get the window handle of our userform. You can include the following code to declare the function in your project (top of module):

```
#If VBA7 Then

    'VBA version 7 compiler, therefore >= Office 2010
    'PtrSafe means function works in 32-bit and 64-bit Office
    'LongPtr type alias resolves to Long (32 bits) in 32-bit Office, or LongLong (64 bits) in 64-bit Office

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, _
        ByVal x As Long, _
        ByVal Y As Long, _
        ByVal cx As Long, _
        ByVal cy As Long, _
        ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

#Else

    'VBA version 6 or earlier compiler, therefore <= Office 2007

    Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
        ByVal X As Long, _
        ByVal Y As Long, _
        ByVal cx As Long, _
        ByVal cy As Long, _
        ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

#End If
```

You can then include the following constants and variable that will be used inside the `SetWindowPos` function:

```
Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Public Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1

#If VBA7 Then
    Public WinHandle As LongPtr
#Else
    Public WinHandle As Long
#End If
```

Hence, we can now get the window handle of our userform:

```
If Val(Application.Version) >= 9 Then
    WinHandle = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", frmCoverScreen.Caption)
Else
    WinHandle = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", frmCoverScreen.Caption)
End If
```

And now having the handle, we can make the userform window appear on top of Excel at all times using the following:

```
SetWindowPos WinHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE
```

Then we only need to set the `.Top` , `.Left` , `.Width` and `.Height` properties of the userform to make sure it covers the part of the screen we need to cover.

Finally, when we no longer need to cover the screen, we can simply unload the form:

```
Unload frmCoverScreen
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write yet another possible solution. Unfortunately it also doesn't work as expected and at this stage I will just have to settle down for what I have.

Comment: Yeah, if that didn't do it. I'd be really surprise if there is another way.

Comment: @johnywhy ― OP explained the reason in the edit made to the question.