# VBA: Macro Error 91 without VBA editor on - no error when it's open

Tags: excel, vba, sap-analysis-for-office

I'm working on a macro that uses the `UIAutomationClient` client to expand the `Analysis` ribbon tab of SAP Analysis for Microsoft Office in Excel, and click one of the buttons available there. This macro is then executed from a `Form Control Button`.

Here's the code:

```
'global object to hold the translations
 Dim translations As Object

Public Enum oConditions
  eUIA_NamePropertyId
  eUIA_AutomationIdPropertyId
  eUIA_ClassNamePropertyId
  eUIA_LocalizedControlTypePropertyId
End Enum

'element name translations for English
Function getEnglishTranslations() As Object
  Set Words = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  'element, element name
  Words.Add "Analysis", "Analysis"
  Words.Add "Lower Ribbon", "Lower Ribbon"
  Words.Add "Design Panel Group", "Design Panel"
  Words.Add "Design Panel Menu", "Design Panel"
  Words.Add "Display Button", "Display"

  Set getEnglishTranslations = Words
End Function

'element name translations for German
Function getGermanTranslations() As Object
   Set Words = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   'element, element name
   Words.Add "Analysis", "Analysis"
   Words.Add "Lower Ribbon", "Unteres Menüband"
   Words.Add "Design Panel Group", "Designbereich"
   Words.Add "Design Panel Menu", "Designbereich"
   Words.Add "Display Button", "Anzeigen"

   Set getGermanTranslations = Words
End Function

Function translate(element As String) As String
    translate = translations(element)
End Function

Sub toggleDisplay()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim oAutomation As New CUIAutomation 'the UI Automation Object
    Dim walker As IUIAutomationTreeWalker
    Set walker = oAutomation.ControlViewWalker
    Dim element As IUIAutomationElement

    'references for elements in the UI tree
    Dim root As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim xl As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim analysisTab As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim xlrib As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim dpanel As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim display As IUIAutomationElement

    'pattern objects which allow the execution of different UI elements' 
    functionality
    Dim oTogglePattern As IUIAutomationTogglePattern
    Dim expcolPattern As IUIAutomationExpandCollapsePattern
    Dim selPattern As IUIAutomationSelectionItemPattern

    'multi-clause condition references to locate the UI elements in the UI 
    tree.
    Dim analysisCond As IUIAutomationCondition
    Dim displayCond As IUIAutomationCondition
    Dim disPanelCond As IUIAutomationCondition

   'stores the language code for the current active language
   Dim languageCode As Integer

   'get the active application language
   languageCode = _
   Application.International(XlApplicationInternational.xlCountryCode)

   'choose the language dictionary based on the active language
   If languageCode = 49 Then
       Set translations = getGermanTranslations
   Else
       Set translations = getEnglishTranslations
   End If

   'get a reference to the UI element tree
   Set root = oAutomation.GetRootElement

   'locate the Excel window
   Set xl = root.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, PropCondition(oAutomation, 
   eUIA_NamePropertyId, _
   "test wb for hidden ribbon - new (delete me).xlsm - Excel"))

   'click the Analysis tab
   Set analysisCond = _ 
   oAutomation.CreateAndCondition(PropCondition(oAutomation, 
   eUIA_NamePropertyId, translate("Analysis")), _
   PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_ClassNamePropertyId, "NetUIRibbonTab"))
   Set analysisTab = xl.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, analysisCond)
   Set selPattern = _ 
   analysisTab.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_SelectionItemPatternId)
   selPattern.Select

   'locate the Design Panel Group
   Set xlrib = xl.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, 
   PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_NamePropertyId, translate("Lower 
   Ribbon")))
   
   Set dpanel = xlrib.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, 
   PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_NamePropertyId, translate("Design Panel 
   Group")))

   'try locating the Display button
   Set displayCond = _ 
   oAutomation.CreateAndCondition(PropCondition(oAutomation, 
   eUIA_NamePropertyId, translate("Display Button")), _
   PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_ClassNamePropertyId, 
   "NetUIRibbonButton"))
   
   Set display = dpanel.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, displayCond)

   'true when the window is shrunk to a point where the display button
   'is part of the dropdown menu under Design Panel
   If display Is Nothing Then

       'expand the Design Panel dropdown first
       Set disPanelCond = _ 
       oAutomation.CreateAndCondition(PropCondition(oAutomation, 
       eUIA_NamePropertyId, translate("Design Panel Menu")), _
    
       PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_ClassNamePropertyId, "NetUIAnchor"))
       Set dpanel = dpanel.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, disPanelCond)
       Set expcolPattern = _ 
       dpanel.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_ExpandCollapsePatternId)
       expcolPattern.Expand
    
      'attempt to locate the Display button again
      Set display = dpanel.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, displayCond)
   End If
    
   'Click the Display button programmatically (FINALLY!!!)
   Set oTogglePattern = display.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_TogglePatternId)
   oTogglePattern.Toggle

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'generate a Condition object with the string to be matched against the 
selected property
Function PropCondition(UiAutomation As CUIAutomation, Prop As oConditions, 
Requirement As String) As IUIAutomationCondition
Select Case Prop
    Case 0
          Set PropCondition = _
          UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, 
          Requirement)
    Case 1
          Set PropCondition = _ 
          UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId, 
          Requirement)
    Case 2
          Set PropCondition = _
          UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, 
          Requirement)
    Case 3
          Set PropCondition = _ 
          UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, 
          Requirement)
    End Select
End Function
```

I have this strange issue that I cannot find the origin for, but I'm able to reproduce it consistently. Every time I click on the button without having the VBA editor opened, I get `run time error 91`.
[image]

This is the line on which the error occurs - `analysisTab` refers to `Nothing` which means it wasn't set for some reason.

[image]

I would appreciate it if you can help me spot the cause of this annoying problem.

Comment: My apologies for overlooking the aspect that the IDE being open causes no error.  The latter sentence would still stand.  What error handling do you have in place for when things aren't found?  `analysisTab = xl.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, analysisCond)` has at least 2 things that would leave `analysisTab is nothing`, which you wouldn't want actions using `analysisTab` to occur when nothing is set.

Comment: That's true! However, the question is more what's causing this different behavior where the Analysis tab reference is properly found and set  in one case and not the other, rather than enhance the error handling. I mean, the structure of the UI tree shouldn't change all of a sudden when a new window is opened/closed. Adding error handling wont do much in terms of executing the macro besides preventing the error from appearing since the code depends entirely on the UI tree . I tried adding a while loop to keep looking for the ribbon tab while it's `nothing` and it got stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Are any of those other variables labeled from an active sheet?   If you're running the macro when looking at "any" sheet, but if you run the macro from the desired, active sheet, that would make a difference.  From what you've provided, code-wise, `Treescope_decendents` is never defined... what is that?  When you have the VBA code open, is that a defined thing, like the cell you're targeting?

Comment: This is a lot of code to scan through, and a lot of the objects used are things we cannot know what they are. In order to trouble-shoot this a [mcve] would be useful. Pare this down to a *minimal, reproducible* example so that others can test. And explain what the objects *are* in the line that fails. What is this `CUIAutomation` / where can we find it in order to test? Is it displayed on-screen? How?

Comment: @Cyril, no all the UI components I'm trying to navigate through are part of the Excel ribbon which is available across all worksheets. `Treescope_descendants` is a constant that is part of the `UIAutomationClient` library. It simply specifies that the code should look for the particular element across all descendants of the UI element for which the method is called. For example if you call `FindFirst` on `xl`, then it will look for an element that satisfies the condition starting with the UI element, `xl`, as the root.

Comment: @CindyMeister, I will try to build a simpler example for you, the problem however is that the elements I'm working with are part of an Excel add-on built by SAP called `Analysis for Office`. I'm not too sure I will be able to reproduce this issue with another set of ribbon elements which are part of the standard Excel ribbon.

Comment: @CindyMeister, the automation framework can be referenced as `UIAutomationClient`. The line fails because it tries to use `analysisTab` when it hasn't been referenced. This means that in the previous line, the object wasn't found the by the UI tree search. This, however is not the case every time because when I have the VBA editor opened, the code executes perfectly fine. I assume that the VBA editor window is not the direct reason for this to work the way it does but it certainly does something that makes the UI tree structure match the expected structure.

Comment: If you are interested in investigating the UI tree yourself, you can use MS's `inspect.exe` which is available as part of the `Accessibility Tools` kit.

Comment: In paring this down, you may be able to isolate where the "disconnect" is occurring. Also, you need to check whether the parameters being passed on that problem line may be "nothing" or at least nothing useful has been assigned to them. FWIW the tool, itself, must be providing the information that's displayed in the Ribbon since it's not possible to analyze that using VBA (it's not exposed outside the project that manages the Ribbon XML).

Comment: @CindyMeister, the parameters are set correctly, however I think I've made a breakthrough in finding the cause. I had not mentioned this previously, but the issue occurs in a workbook uploaded to the SAP Netweaver platform which I accessed through a `Citrix` VM. I now connected to the client's network with a VPN and opened the workbook on my machine and it looks like the issue is gone. I believe the problem may be coming from the fact that the Citrix VM has a different UI tree which I cannot inspect in any way because I have tons of restrictions on my account without any admin rights.

Comment: The second reason that I can think of is the different Excel builds(but same version) running on my machine and the Citrix VM.